# Android ListActivity and TabActivity in same Class

Tags: android, listactivity, tabactivity

I have an array of strings which I want to display using a ListView.
I checked online and found that it can be done by extending my class from ListActivity.
But I am facing a problem.
In my application I have already inherited TabActivity.
Now, I cant inherit multiples classes.
What do I do now ?
I need to keep the tabs and also generate the strings in the ListView.
All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, you don't *need* to inherit from `ListActivity` to use a `ListView`. The only thing inheriting from `ListActivity` buys you is that it automatically finds a `ListView` in your layout with an attribute `android:id="@android:id/list"`, and adds a helper method for setting the list's adapter (along with some other helper methods which are accessible on the `ListView` itself).

So, in your case, since you can not inherit from multiple classes, you can keep the super class of `TabActivity` and simply call `findViewById` to find your `ListView`, and then call [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) on your `ListView` manually.

Comment: What about the definition for onItemSelected() for the ListView ? Can I define the function without inheriting the ListActivity ?

Comment: All the helper methods that `ListActivity` has are exposed on [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) directly.

Comment: I used this code. But there is a problem. only one item, the first one is getting displayed. In my code, only "Afghanistan" is displayed. Could you tell me where I might be going wrong ?
        
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  
        
        String[] items = new String[] {
             "Afghanistan", "Albania"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        list.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: @swayam : That should be asked as a separate question. Don't use comments to ask additional questions - that's not how stackoverflow is meant to work. If wsanville has answered your question correctly then accept the answer and then create a new question to solve any further problems you have.

Comment: From a glance, nothing jumps out as incorrect. Maybe the height of the ListView is wrong in the layout or something. That might be more appropriate as a separate question though.